# "TypeError: c.defaultView.getComputedStyle(...) is null" error in Firefox iframe

Tags: jquery, firefox, iframe

I'm making a page with some iframes in and I keep getting this "TypeError: c.defaultView.getComputedStyle(...) is null" error when loading the inner iframe.
The funny thing is that in neither IE, nor Chrome I get any error.

Due to the nature of the application, I'm bound to use iframes so doing it otherwise is not an option.

So I have my parent page which contains a navigation bar and an iframe to display content (named iframe 1).
In that content iframe I have a navigation bar again and another iframe to display content (named iframe 2).
Loading iframe 2's content happens by javascript:

```
function GoToUrl(strURL, lngTileID) {
    document.getElementById('Dashboard_FrameDIV').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('Dashboard_LoaderDIV').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('Dashboard_Iframe').src = strURL;
    $('.Dashboard_Tile').removeClass('ActiveTile');
    $('#Dashboard_Tile_' + lngTileID).addClass('ActiveTile');
}
```

When first loading iframe 1, there is no src for iframe 2 and I don't get the error. However, from the moment iframe 2's src is set, I do get the error.
I get it in every page that I load into iframe 2 that has jquery included. However in every page itself (the iframe's src) it is only included once.

I reckon it's not something specific in my code that renders this error but more of a principle that I have applied in a wrong way, which is why I don't post much code. If needed, I can post any of my code here.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This error could probably be caused because you are using the old version of `jquery.min.js`.

Try changing that to a higher version: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js and it should work. Let us know if you still see the error!